# How to create calling info dialog when I get a call, when my app is closed?

Tags: android, notifications, dialog, phone-state-listener

How to create a call info dialog as image below, when I get a PHONE_STATE intent

[Call info dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2mHL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

use LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface in your activity like this:

```
abstract Loader        onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)

//Instantiate and return a new Loader for the given ID.

abstract void      onLoadFinished(Loader loader, D data)

//Called when a previously created loader has finished its load.

abstract void      onLoaderReset(Loader loader)

//Called when a previously created loader is being reset, and thus making its data unavailable.
```

implementation of onCreateLoader():

```
@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle args) {
Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader() >> loaderID : " + loaderID);

switch (loaderID) {
case URL_LOADER:
// Returns a new CursorLoader
return new CursorLoader(
this,   // Parent activity context
CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,        // Table to query
null,     // Projection to return
null,            // No selection clause
null,            // No selection arguments
null             // Default sort order
);
default:
return null;
}
}
```

Call your details in onLoadFinished() method:

```
Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor managedCursor) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished()");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        sb.append("<h4>Call Log Details <h4>");
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("\n");

        sb.append("<table>");

        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;

            int callTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (callTypeCode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Outgoing";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Incoming";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "Missed";
                    break;
            }

            sb.append("<tr>")
                    .append("<td>Phone Number: </td>")
                    .append("<td><strong>")
                    .append(phNumber)
                    .append("</strong></td>");
            sb.append("</tr>");
            sb.append("<br/>");
            sb.append("<tr>")
                    .append("<td>Call Type:</td>")
                    .append("<td><strong>")
                    .append(dir)
                    .append("</strong></td>");
            sb.append("</tr>");
            sb.append("<br/>");
            sb.append("<tr>")
                    .append("<td>Date & Time:</td>")
                    .append("<td><strong>")
                    .append(callDayTime)
                    .append("</strong></td>");
            sb.append("</tr>");
            sb.append("<br/>");
            sb.append("<tr>")
                    .append("<td>Call Duration (Seconds):</td>")
                    .append("<td><strong>")
                    .append(callDuration)
                    .append("</strong></td>");
            sb.append("</tr>");
            sb.append("<br/>");
            sb.append("<br/>");
        }
        sb.append("</table>");

        managedCursor.close();

        callLogsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
    }
```

For complete details please see these references:

[link1](https://codexplo.wordpress.com/2014/04/17/how-to-read-call-logs-programmatically-from-android/)

[link two (complete project)](https://github.com/rokon12/call-log)

Comment: Thank you Neo, But y problem is that, when I get call, at same time I want to show a user info dialog on call activity

Comment: This is the core logic. Call the details in onCreateLoader instead of  onload finsh() function.

Comment: See the MainActivity code in link 2 and change the initialize function like this:

Comment: private void initialize() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initialize()");

                getLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, MainActivity.this);
      
        callLogsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call_logs);
    }